# CSS column layout - DIV with dynamic width and same height as sibling

Tags: html, css

I've really hit the wall on this one and need some help. I'm trying to create a two column layout with both widths and heights adjusted to the contents of the left column. It seems to be a rather basic layout, but I'm starting to think it can't be done (without resorting to JS).

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lindsten/Nk64A/) describes what I'm trying to do. It's a container DIV with two DIVs inside, aligned horizontally. The left inner DIV should adjust its size (both width and height) to its content. The right inner DIV (which contains a Google Map) should have the same height as the left one while filling up the remaining width of the container.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">
        This DIV should adjust<br/>
        both its width and height<br/>
        to its content, not taking up<br/>
        more space than needed!<br/>
        <br/><br/><br/>
        More content here...
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        Google Map here.
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried everything I know and all tricks I've found, but no success!

```
#container {
    background-color: #EEE;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#container div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}
#left {
    background-color: lightblue;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
#right {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    height: 100%; /* THIS IS WHAT I WANT, BUT IT WON'T WORK, OF COURSE */
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I've found many similar questions, but in all those cases the left DIV/column had a fixed width, which makes it a whole lot easier.

Any input is much appreciated, especially if it works in IE9+ (and modern browsers)!

**Edit**

Some clarification. The purpose of the right column is to hold a Google map and consequently the map is supposed to fill up the entire DIV. Try setting a fixed height (e.g. 100px) for #right in the fiddle that I link to above and you will see the map showing up.

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8VBXS/)

css :

```
    .container {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #EEE;
}
.column {
    float: left;
    background-color: grey;
    padding-bottom: 1000px;
    margin-bottom: -1000px;
}


p {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

html

```
    <script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>


<div class="container">

<div class="column">

        This DIV should adjust<br/>
        both its width and height<br/>
        to its content, not taking up<br/>
        more space than needed!<br/>
        <br/><br/><br/>
        More content here...

</div>

<div class="column">

<div id="map"></div>

</div>

</div>

<p>
    The right DIV (which contains a Google Map)
    should be the same height as the left DIV,
    while filling up the remaining width.
</p>
<p>How to do that?</p>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Perhaps it wasn't clear from my description, but the Google map is supposed to fill up the right column. Try setting a fixed height (e.g. 100px) in the fiddle that I linked to in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here what I came up with -> [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Nk64A/8/)

When you remove the `overflow` property of your `#right div` it stretches as expected. However in this case you won't be able to hide the overflowed content.

**CSS**

```
#right {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    height: 100%; /* THIS WON'T WORK */  // height works as expected      
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Perhaps it wasn't clear from my description, but the Google map is supposed to fill up the right column. Try setting a fixed height (e.g. 100px) in the fiddle that I linked to in my question.